# Where can I find the source code for Akka actor latest version?

Tags: akka, actor

I am trying to find the Scala source code for Akka actors.
I know there is a GitHub repo at the following address for Akka actor.
https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-actor

However, when I try finding a specific class, e.g. akka.actor.ActorContext, in this repo (e.g. https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor), I cannot find it.

So, I was wondering, how can I obtain the entire source code for Akka actors. I am interested in the untyped version.

Comment: I was trying to search for it aa well. I was using the `go to file` at the github but didnt find. Maybe it is inside an object and this is why you cannot find. I suggest to download the source code and execute a `grep -rin "ActorContext" .` in the entire source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the repo first:

```
git clone https://github.com/akka/akka.git
```

The reason you can't find `akka.actor.ActorContext` is because it's defined as `trait` in this Scala source file: `akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorCell.scala`